# Create "Edit Item" Button for the Default Form for user to edit their info [Sharepoint 2013]

Tags: custom-form, form, content-editor-web-part, edit-form, edit

I am trying to create an "Edit Item" button that does the same function as the "Edit Item" button of the top left of the ribbon. My customer finds the ribbon Edit Item button difficult to find for users and wants to incorporate the button on the actual default form itself. I was thinking of using a Webpart (Script Editor or Content Editor) to achieve this. Does anyone have any ideas? I am very new to Sharepoint,so if any code could be provided it would be greatly appreciated.

[In this first picture, it shows the list item. This is not the location I want to edit it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKQi7.png)

[In this second image, it shows what happens when you click on the list item. It displays the form and the information submitted. It is from this point the user will want to edit their information. Where it says "Edit" in blue is where I would roughly like the button to be.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8VLG.png)

Comment: You can always add the OOTB edit button to your list view.

Comment: Or do you wanna switch to edit from the display form?

Comment: OOB method is what mentioned below , for adding a button in form you may have to use javascript!

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses! And the OOTB button might suffice but they were wanting a button in the actual form itself. When they click the list item it opens it up as a Display Form, and they want to see the button on that view. They might be okay with seeing the Edit button on the list view, but I might look into how I can incorporate the Javascript method if it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

1. Select "Modify view"
2. Mark the column **Edit (Link to edit item)**. See image 1.

You can see the result in image 2.

[image]

[image]